# SetInterval "Stacking" on top of each other

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setinterval

I'm working on this project which uses setInterval and I'm having a little trouble understanding how setInterval works. The problem I'm having is that the each time I call setInterval the function seems to stack on top of each other resulting in the object appearing multiple times rapidly. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong in this case. Can someone please help me out thanks.

```
const [hit, setHit] = useState(0)
const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
var timer = null
var funcCalls = 0
const hitSound = new Audio("/hit.wav")
useEffect(()=>{
    timer = setInterval(moveSquare, 2000)
},[])
function handleHit(){
    hitSound.play()
    setHit(hit+1)
    resetSquare()
}
function resetSquare(){
    clearInterval(timer)
    moveSquare()
    timer = setInterval(moveSquare, 2000)
}
function moveSquare(){
    const gameContainer = document.getElementById("game-container")
    const height = gameContainer.offsetHeight
    const width = gameContainer.offsetWidth
    const square = document.getElementById("square")
    square.style.top = (Math.random() * (height - 100)) + "px";
    square.style.left = (Math.random() * (width - 100)) + "px";
}
return (
    <>
    <section className='game-section'>
        <div className='counter'>
            {hit}
            {count}
        </div>
        <div className='game-container' id = "game-container">
            <div className="square" id = "square" onClick={handleHit}></div>
        </div>
    </section>
    </>
)
```

Comment: What happens when you comment out `moveSquare()` from your `resetSquare` function?

Comment: The object (square) won't move immediately, but I still get the stacking of the setInterval

Comment: This isnt a great answer to your question, but ive always had trouble with intervals and component re-rendering, what you are trying to do is quite simple using something like lodash's debounce, do you think that might be a better solution?

Comment: @Dave answer is the right one

Comment: This is beside the main question, but it’s generally a bad idea to mix direct DOM manipulation and React rendering. Use one or the other, not both. At the very least, use React refs instead of `getElementById`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason for that is elsewhere: your component (and/or and of its parent) is recreated. There are just few reasons in general but it's hard to point a specific line of code without debugging:

- Either conditional rendering (e.g. showing spinner during request and after render element with children again)
- Or different `key` prop is provided
- Or by mistake you put component declaration(function or class or wrap into HOC) inside of other component's render code and every time parent is rerendered, component's declaration becomes referentially different

Another root cause: your `useEffect` does not have cleanup. While it should. And even without first reason, you would not have multiple concurrent timers but you still would have timer that would not stop when you're navigating away.

```
useEffect(()=>{
    timer = setInterval(moveSquare, 2000)
    return () => clearInterval(timer);
},[])
```

More on cleanup in official docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup

Comment: Good advice. And there is no need to cancel and restart the interval timer in handleHit() and resetSquare(). The same interval timer can keep running, just alter the other state variables. But anyway, you have a few solutions here re: why your timer is stacking on itself.

Comment: @Dave yeah, those operations on timer look suspiciously redundant

Answer (score 1):

It's because the `timer` value isn't saved across renders so you can't cancel it.

```
var timer = null // <-- no
const [timer, setTimer] = useState(null) // <-- yes
...
// later in useEffect() and resetSquare()
// save the timer using setTimer(timer)
```

Comment: By using `useState` they will have one extra useless rerender upon initializing it from `null` to something. From the other side, using `useRef` is typical for things like timers